# Use of final keyword before oncreate to call txt file from assets (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, final

I want to read a TXT file from assets folder. But I have to do this on before onCreate (on main class). So it should be ***final***. My code;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String host = LoadDataTxt("host.txt");
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ....
    public String LoadDataTxt(String inFile) {
        String tContents = "";
        try {
            InputStream stream = getAssets().open(inFile);
            int size = stream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            stream.read(buffer);
            stream.close();
            tContents = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return tContents;
    }
}
```

The error is: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method LoadDataTxt(String) from the type MainActivity.
How can I read the txt file from assets **before onCreate** and make it **final**? Or how can i call LoadDataTxt method from main class? Thanks.

Comment: you should make your `LoadDataTxt` function `public static`.

Comment: It says: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAssets() from the type ContextWrapper. The problem is a context with that getAssets method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the fact the host String is declared static, and you actually need an instance of the activity to have a context which is necessary to call getAssets().

Do you really need it to be a static member of your Activity class ?

Comment: This is OK for me. But it won't work.
final String host = LoadDataTxt("host.txt");

Comment: The app crashes with this:
final String host = LoadDataTxt("host.txt");

Comment: I think the problem is context of getAssets.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare LoadDataTxt method as static to remove the error you are getting.

Comment: It gives me error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAssets() from the type ContextWrapper

Comment: Maybe best solution is to remove static from host variable and assign value to host in onCreate method. Ignore this as finall member variables need initializing before constructor has cmpleted

Comment: The app crashes with this:
final String host = LoadDataTxt("host.txt");

Comment: I think the problem is context of getAssets.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `host` string as class variable,So change

```
 public static final String host = LoadDataTxt("host.txt");
```

to

```
String host;
```

and get its value in onCreate method as

```
host = LoadDataTxt("host.txt");
```

Comment: I know it. But I want the host should be final. The only place which I can make it final is, before oncreate (on main class).

Comment: @user3051668 do you want it in `MainActivity`? then what is problem with above solution.please elaborate.

Comment: If I use it with "final", the app works perfect. But without final; some of my AsynTask don't work. So it should be Final and the value should not change.

Comment: @user3051668 pass `host` value  as parameter in AsyncTask.